# launch photo gallery from iphone App

Tags: iphone, gallery, photo, launch

Is it possible to launch (redirect the user to) the native photo gallery application of iphone from my app, similar to emails? Is this now possible in 4.2 sdk?

Comment: I don't know which example it is, but you can display photos from the photos app within your own app. Check the apple sample code.

Answer (score 6):

For this, you have to create and present a `UIImagePickerController` like this:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary; 
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

You can change `imagePicker.sourceType` to `imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;` if you want the user to use the camera instead.

The delegate method: `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` will give you the image in the `info` dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to launch the native iphone application photo gallery and not simply being able to pick an image from the photo gallery, i was wondering is that is possible w/ the latest SDK

Comment: I am not aware of any API which makes launching the Photos app possible. Here is a list of apps which you can launch using custom URL schemes: http://applookup.com/2010/09/iphone-apps-with-special-url-shortcuts/